# Calculated column, Greater of two dates < Today If formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I want to see if the greater of [date1] and [date2] is less then today.

Currently i have it for one column - =IF([date1]<TODAY(),"Yes","")

But how do I make this formula to include the logic of using the greater of date1 and date 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MAX` function

```
=IF(MAX([date1], [date2])<TODAY(),"Yes","")
```